# OpenCV "conflicting declaration" issue at compilation on armv7l (Odroid XU4)

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, arm, odroid

I'm trying to compile OpenCV 3.4.0 from sources but I'm running into a conflicting declaration issue between QT and OpenGL.
Upgrading from QT4 to QT5 solved some issues but not all.
It looks like GLsizeiptr and GLintptr are declared in both the OpenGL headers and the QT headers.

I tried to replace

```
#include <GL/glx.h>
```

with

```
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
```

in window_QT.cpp but that only created more declaration issues.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

(My machine is an armv7l (Odroid XU4) running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

The cmake command I'm running:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_QT=5 -DWITH_OPENGLES=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DBUILD_TBB=ON -DENABLE_VFPV3=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON ..

make -j8
```

the errors I'm getting:

```
[ 62%] Built target opencv_videoio
[ 63%] Built target opencv_superres
[ 63%] Building CXX object 

modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/release/modules/highgui/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_highgui_RELEASE.gch: not used because `TBB_USE_GCC_BUILTINS' is defined [-Winvalid-pch]
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:32,
                 from /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:59:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:466:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr’
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/qopengl.h:95:0,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:54,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/QtGui:32,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGLDepends:4,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:3,
                 from /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.h:50,
                 from /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:47:
/usr/include/GLES3/gl31.h:77:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr’
 typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr;
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:32,
                 from /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:59:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:467:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr’
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/qopengl.h:95:0,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:54,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/QtGui:32,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGLDepends:4,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:3,
                 from /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.h:50,
                 from /home/odroid/temporary_cmake_binary_dir/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:47:
/usr/include/GLES3/gl31.h:78:26: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr’
 typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr;
                          ^
[ 63%] Built target gen_opencv_python_source
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:129: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5307: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: I just tried a fresh install with latest version of opencv cloned directly from github and the install went flawlessly.